# How do I pass multiple datasets to my view in sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, orm, express, sails.js

I want to be able to pass multiple data sets to my view. Here is how I am currently doing it in my controller:

```
  transactions: function (req, res) {

    var queryexpenses = 'select * from expense order by name';

    Expense.query(queryexpenses, function (err, expense) {
        this.expenses = expense;
    });

    if (req.param('filter')) {
        var where = 'where fk_expense = ' + req.param('expensefilter');
        where += ' and datePosted > "' + req.param('yearfilter') + '-01-01" ';
        where += ' and datePosted < "' + req.param('yearfilter') + '-12-31" ';
    } else {
        var where = 'where fk_expense IS NULL';
    }

    var query = 'select * from accounting ' + where + '  order by description';

    Accounting.query(query, function (err, trans) {
        this.transactions = trans;
    });

    var total = 0;
    _.each(this.transactions, function (element, index, list) {
        // format dates
        element.datePosted = dateFormat(element.datePosted, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
        var tmp0 = element.amount
        var tmp1 = tmp0.replace(/ /g, '');
        var tmp2 = parseFloat(tmp1);
        total += tmp2;
    });

    this.total = total.toFixed(2);
    return res.view();
}
```

This is the only way I am able to accomplish what Im trying to do but there are problems which I believe are caused by me putting the query objects in the "this" scope. The first problem is the page will crash after server restart on first reload. The second problem is everything seems to happen one step behind. What I mean is if I issue commands on the UI (eg submit a form) nothing will happen unless I take the same action twice.

So how do I pass multiple sets of data to my views without scoping them in "this"?

Answer (score 0):

```
res.view({
    corndogs: [{name: 'Hank the Corndog'}, {name: 'Lenny the Corndog'}]
});
```

Here is the relevant docs page: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views

Also, it looks like you're not taking full advantage of [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) for making SQL queries.